# Client <> Query <> Subquery Bookkeeping

Tags: concurrency, clojure

**Context**

- I am making a system, where different clients issue queries
- A query is resolved by issuing a set of subqueries
- I have an invalidation-worker, which gets notified when subqueries go stale

**Goal**

- When a subquery goes stale, I want to notify the clients which have made this subquery

**Solution**

To do this, I am thinking of keeping a mapping. Here's a rough solution you can play with in the REPL:

```
(ns play
  (:require [clojure.core.async :as a :refer [go <! go-loop >!]]))

(def recordings (atom {}))

(defn record-subquery! [client-id query-n subquery-n]
  (swap! recordings update subquery-n
         (fn [prev]
           (let [prev (or prev #{})]
             (conj prev [client-id query-n])))))

(defn go-subquery [client-id query-n subquery-n]
  (go
    (<! (a/timeout (rand-int 2000)))
    (record-subquery! client-id query-n subquery-n)
    {:client-id client-id
     :query-n query-n
     :subquery-n subquery-n}))

(defn go-query [client-id query-n]
  (go
    (let [subquery-ns (range query-n (+ query-n 5))]
      {:client-id client-id
       :query-n query-n
       :subqueries (->> subquery-ns
                        (map (partial go-subquery client-id query-n))
                        a/merge
                        (a/into [])
                        <!)})))

(comment
  (go (prn (<! (go-query :a 1)))))

(def client-chans {:a (a/chan)
                   :b (a/chan)})

(defn client-worker [client-id query-chan]
  (go-loop []
    (when-some [q (<! query-chan)]
      (prn (format "queried id = %s q = %s" client-id (<! (go-query client-id q))))
      (recur))))

(def invalidation-chan (a/chan))

(defn invalidation-broadcaster []
  (go (loop []
        (<! (a/timeout 1500))
        (when (>! invalidation-chan (rand-int 10))
          (recur)))))

(defn invalidation-worker [chan]
  (go-loop []
    (when-some [sq-id (<! chan)]
      (let [subs (->> sq-id (@recordings))]
        (prn (format "invalidating sq-id = %s subs = %s" sq-id subs))
        (doseq [[client-id query-n] subs]
          (>! (client-id client-chans) query-n))
        (recur)))))

(comment
  (do (client-worker :a (:a client-chans))
      (client-worker :b (:b client-chans))
      (invalidation-worker invalidation-chan)
      (invalidation-broadcaster))

  (a/close! invalidation-chan)
  (go (>! (:a client-chans) 1)))
```

**Problem with the solution**

I am a bit sad that `record-subquery!` is nested under go-subquery. This makes `go-query` stateful. I do it though to avoid the following race condition:

```
T0: go-query starts 
T1: subquery-1 completes 
T2: subquery-1 is invalidated 
T3: subquery-2 completes 
T4: go-query completes
```

In this scenario, we would miss the `T2` update.

Would you do this differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## invariant

You didn't write down any invariants,
and the problem statement was not entirely clear.
Here's what I heard.

We return valid query results,
built up from sub-queries that are time consuming.
Each sub-query may be invalidated at any time,
which affects the overall result.

This sounds
[racy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Data_race)
to me, as invalidation messages can be sent at any time
right up until a query result is about to be returned.
The strongest promise the current code could make is to
say that immediately before returning it checked for invalidations
and found an empty queue.

### stronger promise

Suppose the channel marks all incoming messages with a timestamp or
[Lamport clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport_timestamp).
And it returns a similar counter when reporting that
zero messages remain. Now we can sensibly describe the validity
of a query result by annotating it with that counter.
There may be subsequent invalidation messages, but they
will be marked with counter values greater than
the one in our valid result.

---

## queue depth

Consider specifying a "large" value for the channel size
so that invalidators are unlikely to block.
The current default size of `1` invites lock-step
progress between producer and consumer.

---

## post-processing

Consider performing all (time consuming!) sub-queries unconditionally,
and then doing (quick) validity checks afterward, in the interest
of simplicity.
The idea would be to go through a tight validation loop
which can exit as soon as it sees that the channel is empty.